# Select top 2 prices for each symbol

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am wanting to grab the top two recent prices for each symbol in table below

if i wanted only the most recent price i would
"select distinct symbol, price from  table_1 order by date, time"

getting two most recent prices is leaving me a little stuck

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
[symbol] [nchar](15) NOT NULL,
[price] [float] NULL,
[date] [date] NOT NULL,
[time] [time](7) NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Your syntax is SQL Server, so I'm changing the tag to sql-server.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by symbol order by date desc, time desc) as seqnum
      from table_1 t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

As a note.  To get the most recent price, you would *not* do:

```
select distinct symbol, price
from table_1
order by date, time;
```

This would generate a syntax error, because `date` and `time` are not in the `select` clause.  If you removed the `order by`, you would simply get a list of all distinct `symbol`/`price` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

How about `select top 2 symbol, price from table_1 order by date, time` ?

Comment: that only grabs 2 rows, kind of need it to loop for all symbols. if i had 100 symbols it would be 200 rows

Otherwise i may need to add an extra column as insert time
and filter by past hour